# Ошибка "vector subscript out of range" в цикле

Tags: c++

Хочу создать карточную игру. Пока создаю сам движок игры и не могу реализовать функцию через вектор. Вот код:

```
typedef pair<</>int, int> card; // nominal and suit of card
typedef vector<</>card> Cards;
typedef vector<</>Cards> CardsPlayers;

CardsPlayers CCards;
int _TurnPlayer;

bool Core::PlayerTurn(int nominal, int suit)
{
    card Card;
    Card.first = nominal;
    Card.second = suit;
    for (auto iter = CCards[_TurnPlayer].begin(); iter < CCards[_TurnPlayer].end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (*iter == Card)
        {
            CCards[_TurnPlayer].erase(iter);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Функция (метод) будет искать карту игрока, которой он сделает ход, и удалять из вектора карту как указано выше. Но у меня вылетает ошибка при отладке:

> Expression: vector subscript out of range"

Как можно исправить такую ошибку? Пишу на VS2012.

Comment: Ну посмотриет в отладчике к какому элементу вектора вы обращаетесь..

Comment: Как? Я могу только сказать что ошибка возникает в строчке " for(auto iter = CCards[_TurnPlayer].begin(); iter < CCards[_TurnPlayer].end(); ++iter)". А посмотреть не знаю как.

Comment: Вам нужно учиться пользоваться отладчиком, без этого вам будет очень печально.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решается очень просто: нужно обеспечить, чтобы неотрицательное значение переменной `_TurnPlayer` было **строго меньше** значения  выражения`CCards.size()`

Также вместо цикла лучше использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::find`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>` . Например

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

bool Core::PlayerTurn(int nominal, int suit)
{
    auto it = std::find( CCards[_TurnPlayer].begin(),
                         CCards[_TurnPlayer].end(),
                         card( nominal, suit ) );

    return it == CCards[_TurnPlayer].end() ? 
           false : 
           ( CCards[_TurnPlayer].erase(it), true );
}
```

Comment: @Max_Advanced Не за что.:)